# How to render an array in a pdf in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to render an array that contains arrays of strings into a pdf document. However, it is unable to render, although it will render Text. This is the code I am using.

```
    @MainActor
func render() -> URL {
    let renderer = ImageRenderer(content:
                                    List {
        ForEach(docnote.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(docnote[index], id: \.self) { info in
                    Text(info)
                }
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteStorageItem) // Add onDelete modifier for second List
    }
    )
    let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "output.pdf")
    renderer.render { size, context in
        var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
            return
        }
        pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
        context(pdf)
        pdf.endPDFPage()
        pdf.closePDF()
    }

    return url
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to render flattened version of ListRepresentable<CollectionViewListDataSource, SelectionManagerBox>.
> Unable to render flattened version of ListRepresentable<CollectionViewListDataSource, SelectionManagerBox>.
> 2023-04-15 20:13:41.812705-0400 PrescriptionTracker[4906:1289529] [ShareSheet] Only support loading options for CKShare and SWY types.
> 2023-04-15 20:13:41.843331-0400 PrescriptionTracker[4906:1289529] [ShareSheet] error fetching item for URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/739F6D91-7F58-48DA-B3FB-1F9A4F0BE8BA/Documents/output.pdf : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened."

Comment: Try removing the onDelete modifier. I don’t think the renderer supports any modifiers with logic.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Still no rendering, it is just a black screen.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Lists and Tables. Remove the List block and just define with the ForEach so essentially you are just rendering out a for loop of Text views. Seems that PDF rendering only supports really basic views.